Unable to logon using LDAP to Active Directory User when "Log On To" restriction configured
I have an Active Directory user, and I can successfully connect to it using LDAP search with the following command:
ldapsearch -x -H <AD_server> -D "cn=user_test,cn=users,dc=<dc1>,dc=<dc2>" -w <password> -b "cn=<dc1>,cn=<dc2>" 

However, when I set the "Log On To" restriction in AD and specify a particular computer name, I encounter the following error:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090434, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4f7c

I have already joined my Linux machine to the AD domain using these steps:
sudo apt install -y realmd libnss-sss libpam-sss sssd sssd-tools adcli samba-common-bin oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir packagekit
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname <hostname>.<domain_name>
echo 'nameserver <ldap_server_ip>' > /etc/resolv.conf
realm discover <domain_name>
realm --verbose join -U '<username>' <domain_name> 

I verified the computer is joined to the domain both by using realm list and by checking in the AD UI.
Could anyone help me understand why the "Log On To" restriction might be causing this authentication issue, and how I can resolve it? Thank you!


Could anyone help me understand why the "Log On To" restriction might be causing this authentication issue, and how I can resolve it?

"Logon to" is only for accounts that logon interactively using a specific Windows desktop workstation on a LAN, for the purpose of running specific application(s) on that workstation using RPC. It cannot be used not for accounts that need to logon over the network using LDAP, or another mechanism that cannot present the workstation name on RPC.
You need to find another configuration setting to accomplish the objective, and is not known to be incompatible with existing settings and configuration.

The workstations (aka "Log on to") attribute is deprecated:
"This user attribute should not be used anymore. To manage what accounts can logon to which workstations, we recommend using the "Allow Log on locally" and "Deny Log on locally" or "Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services" and "Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services"."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-userworkstations

"This BZ has been evaluated multiple times over the last year and we assessed that it might be valuable feature to someone but the audience for this feature is very small."
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1693248
